# How to load .txt with numpy 2d array of dictionaries (objects)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I tried to load a .txt file with numpy with the `numpy.loadtxt("grid_data.txt", dtype=object)` function but it did not return the expected result.
I am working on a game which is a grid-like game so I want to save data for some tiles. I'd like to use dictionaries instead of lists as to only save data to that tile when needed, and not have the other tiles with no data (like a grass, dirt, etc.) have data that is not necessary.

(I am not very experienced in Numpy, sorry for the possible bad code)

I have the following:

`np.loadtxt('grid_data.txt',dtype=object)`

With a grid_data.txt as something like this (but then 500x500):

```
{} {} {}
{} {} {}
{} {} {}
```

etc.

I generated and saved the file with `np.savetxt(f, grid_data, fmt="%s")` where the grid_data variable is the np.array with: (the np.array has a width and height of 500)
[[{}, {}, {}, ... {}, {}, {}], ... ,[{}, {}, {}, ... {}, {}, {}]]

I tried to load this .txt file in with the numpy.loadtxt function with dtype as object, but it returned the following (I tried it on the 500x500 array txt file):

`[['{}' '{}' '{}' ... '{}' '{}' '{}'] ['{}' '{}' '{}' ... '{}' '{}' '{}'] ['{}' '{}' '{}' ... '{}' '{}' '{}']]`

How do I get the array to this format?
`[[{},{},{}...{},{},{}], [{},{},{}...{},{},{}] [{},{},{}...{},{},{}]]` 
So that I can actually 'use' the dictionaries instead of '{}'?

Any help on how I can overcome this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to change the format of the file? This is not a great format to store the data you want

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the file in full? It looks like you can just eval the dictionary string

Comment: To get `dict` from these strings '{}', you have to use `eval`.  `loadtxt/genfromtxt` won't do that for you.  The best you can get from those readers are these strings.  The `csv` format is meant for numeric and simple string data, stuff that can be displayed in regular rows and columns (imagine original spread sheet data).  It isn't intended for complex python objects.

Comment: It is not recommended to use eval unless you absolutely have to. Prefer json.loads then ast.literal_eval and only then eval.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but are these all empty `dict`, or do they actually have content?  And it, so what kind of content?  Why a numpy array; lists are better for holding objects like `dict`.  `numpy` doesn't provide any special handling for `objects`.

Comment: @arrmansa, I don't think this user is going to be importing these files from unknown sources.  This is just for temporary transfer and saving between game sessions.  Yes there are "safer" alternatives to `eval`, which they achieve by limiting the content of these `dict`.  The OP has only shown empty `dict`, which doesn't give us a realistic idea of what he's actually trying to save.

Comment: Consider using `pickle` to save your `dict`, whether in lists or arrays.  You can't read it as text, but it easily handles complicated structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a great format to store the data you want. If you are able to change the format, you could save the dictionaries as a *json* file which contains a list of all dictionaries, and the desired shape of the matrix. For example, if your file looks like so:

```
{
  "shape": [3, 3],
  "data": [{"foo": 0, "bar": 0},
           {"foo": 10, "bar": 1},
           {"foo": 20, "bar": 2},
           {"foo": 30, "bar": 3},
           {"foo": 40, "bar": 4},
           {"foo": 50, "bar": 5},
           {"foo": 60, "bar": 6},
           {"foo": 70, "bar": 7},
           {"foo": 80, "bar": 8}]
}
```

You could read it with the standard `json` library

```
file_data = json.load("filename.json")
```

And then create the numpy array out of `file_data["data"]` and reshape it to `file_data["shape"]`:

```
my_arr = np.array(file_data["data"]).reshape(file_data["shape"])
```

Which gives the desired array:

```
array([[{'foo': 0, 'bar': 0}, {'foo': 10, 'bar': 1},
        {'foo': 20, 'bar': 2}],
       [{'foo': 30, 'bar': 3}, {'foo': 40, 'bar': 4},
        {'foo': 50, 'bar': 5}],
       [{'foo': 60, 'bar': 6}, {'foo': 70, 'bar': 7},
        {'foo': 80, 'bar': 8}]], dtype=object)
```

---

To save this array back to a json file, you simply do the reverse:

```
json_obj = {"shape": my_arr.shape, "data": my_arr.flatten().tolist()}

with open("filname.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(json_obj, f, indent=2)
```

which outputs this to your file:

```
{
  "shape": [
    3,
    3
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "foo": 0,
      "bar": 0
    },
    {
      "foo": 10,
      "bar": 1
    },
    {
      "foo": 20,
      "bar": 2
    },
    {
      "foo": 30,
      "bar": 3
    },
    {
      "foo": 40,
      "bar": 4
    },
    {
      "foo": 50,
      "bar": 5
    },
    {
      "foo": 60,
      "bar": 6
    },
    {
      "foo": 70,
      "bar": 7
    },
    {
      "foo": 80,
      "bar": 8
    }
  ]
}
```